# Best way to create a child object from its parent

Tags: java, inheritance, downcast

Which is the best way to create a child given a parent with data?
Would it be ok to have a method with all parents values on the child class as:

```
public class Child extends Person {
  public Child(Parent p) {
    this.setParentField1(p.getParentField1());
    this.setParentField2(p.getParentField2());
    this.setParentField3(p.getParentField3());
    // other parent fields.
  }
}
```

to copy parent data ti child object?

```
Child child = new Child(p);
```

Comment: extends Person () { No brackets required.

Comment: Why does your `Child` need to be passed a `Parent` to be created?

Comment: @tieTYT maybe, just maybe, the person wants an exact child-clone including all his benefits and bad habits =\

Comment: yeah, the child is the parent but it has some extra fields.

Answer (score 18):

I would recommend creating a constructor in the parent class that accepts an object of type `Parent`.

```
public class Child extends Parent {
  public Child(Parent p) {
     super(p);
  }
}

public class Parent {
   public Parent(Parent p){
      //set fields here
   }
}
```

Comment: creating a `Person` object from a `Person` object seems somewhat pointless..

Comment: That is the whole point of the question i suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler is

```
       public class Child extends Parent {
             public Child(Parent p) {
             //Set fields with parent
           }
       }
```

Your child object always has access to its parent's fields given the appropriate access modifiers are in place.